# Swift Timer Target To Prevent Retain Cycle

Tags: swift, timer, crash

Before iOS 10, using Timer directly will generate Retain Cycle, so I used Runtime to build the code, but the code crashed at build. I don’t know where the null pointer was generated.

```
var time: Timer?
var target: NSObject?


target = NSObject()
let selector = #selector(timePrint)
if let method = class_getMethodImplementation(self.classForCoder, selector) {
     let IMP = method_getImplementation(method)
     let encodeing = method_getTypeEncoding(method)
     class_addMethod(target?.classForCoder, selector, IMP, encodeing)
     time = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: target!, selector: selector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Comment: There really is no need for all this `class_getMethodImplementation` etc. If there's a danger of a retain cycle, break it.

Comment: There’s a closure based Timer API, why don’t you just use that?

Answer (score -1):

Because I want to be compatible with the old version before iOS 10.So I can only do this.The currently known methods are as follows:

- Mimic the closure of the system

```
extension Timer {
    class func rp_scheduledTimer(timeInterval ti: TimeInterval, repeats yesOrNo: Bool, closure: @escaping (Timer) -> Void) -> Timer {
        return self.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: ti, target: self, selector: #selector(RP_TimerHandle(timer:)), userInfo: closure, repeats: yesOrNo)
}
    
    @objc class func RP_TimerHandle(timer: Timer) {
        var handleClosure = { }
        handleClosure = timer.userInfo as! () -> ()
        handleClosure()
    }
}
```

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      time = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] (timer) in
            // do something
      })
} else {
      time = Timer.rp_scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, repeats: true, closure: { [weak self] (timer) in
            // do something
      })
}
```

- DispatchSource to replace Timer

```
var source: DispatchSourceTimer?

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

} else {

   source = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(flags: [], queue: .global())
   source.schedule(deadline: .now(), repeating: 2)
   source.setEventHandler {
       // do something...
   }
   source.resume()
}
```

- `NSProxy`

Comment: This is unnecessarily elaborate. We were all using Timer / NSTimer before iOS 10 and it is/was simple to avoid retain cycle. You simply have to `invalidate` the timer at some time prior to `deinit` (e.g. `viewWillDisappear`). It is true that a nice alternative is the DispatchSource timer, but you still have to cancel the timer. See my https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/ddd2b9f22660b61a2878cf60812a814ecc8b85b1/bk1ch12p499cancelableTimer/ch12p325NotificationLeaker/CancelableTimer.swift